# Loop until null value is given

Tags: php, loops, null

I've a third party library that returns values from a function and gives null if no value is present (not a database).

I've got the first value and I want to use it to return the second one and use the second one to return the third and so on.  When a null value is returned, this loop should stop.

So the function uses an ID to get the next value eg: `getNextValue($id)`. The return of this function is `value` or `null`.

So how should I include this function in a loop that uses a start value and returns the second, and uses the second to return the third and so on, until it returns a null value so it stops?

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($value = getNextValue($id)) ...
```

Comment: fine how to use the first $id and return the subsequent values to use in the same function

Comment: `while ($id = getNextValue($id))`?

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($id = getNextValue($id)) { 
//this will keep passing $id to the function over and over again
//Assuming your function will return different input or a null, this will work.

//code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (null !== ($value = getNextValue($id))) {

}
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster what is yoda style?

Comment: `null == $value` instead of `$value == null`. "a programmer you are" vs "you are a programmer"

Comment: @goat Thank you, exactly what I needed (only null value, not space)